# Alt+tab displayed on current monitor in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, application-switcher, gnome-shell

I'm working with two monitors connected to my laptop, one over mDP, and the second one over HDMI.

I have windows arranged on both monitors and when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> between the windows, the switcher is shown only on the primary monitor which is not ideal.

How do I make the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher show on the monitor where the cursor is located, and optionally list only windows located on that monitor?

I'm using default Gnome coming with 17.10 install.

Thanks!

Comment: You have not included which desktop environment you are using (I guess gnome). On KDE this is standard behavior (though as to be expected not the part with only the windows on that monitor)

Comment: Yes, it's the default Gnome. I've ammended the question.

Comment: Why does this still have no answer?? :(

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/pospeselr/AltTabUltimate) looks relevant, but it's not being developed any more, and I haven't tested it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/968950/alttab-displayed-on-current-monitor-in-ubuntu-17-10 please check this link for more clarification

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following gnome shell extension satisfies your desire:

**Coverflow Alt-Tab**

Ether install it from the [GNOME Extensions homepage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/)

or from [GitHub](https://github.com/dmo60/CoverflowAltTab).

Change your setup:

[image: Settings of **Coverflow Alt-Tab**]

Comment: This does not solve the problem